# Smart indexing by time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have dataframe like that:

```
| Date    | Device | Status |
| 1990/01 | 50     | ON     |
| 1990/01 | 20     | ON     |
| 1990/03 | 25     | ON     |
| 1990/05 | 50     | OFF    |
| 2000/01 | 20     | OFF    |
```

Basically, I log change of devices status when it occurs, but this is not periodic so 'Date' column is not 'continous'.
I want to query device status at any date with some simple logic E.g.

1. `df(device=50, date=1990/01) -> ON` - easy
2. `df(device=50, date=1990/02) -> ON` , there is no 1990/02 for device 50, but when device is set to specific Status, then it stays in it unless there is no change
3. `df(device=50, date=1990/05) -> OFF`
4. `df(device=50, date=2000/09) -> OFF`
5. `df(device=50, date=1900/01) -> OFF`, this is a tricky one, before first ON, device is in OFF status

The second case is with different statuses, but to make question concise I'll keep it the same.
Behavior is exactly the same except point 5. when we assume that device before first logged ON status is also in ON status.
There could be more statuses but logic to decide device status is exactly the same.

How to do it in pandastic way?

Comment: In your description number 1. and number 5. have same inputs but different outputs. Please correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there has to be define all possible dates for select in [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) which is used for [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) of [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)ed DataFrame. `NaN`s are replaced first by forward filling and all first `NaN` values to `OFF` by `fillna`:

```
print (df)
      Date  Device Status
0  1990/01      50     ON
1  1990/01      20     ON
2  1990/03      25     ON
3  1990/05      50    OFF
4  1990/05      20    OFF <-changed for smaller output df

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

rng = pd.date_range('1989-10-01', '1991-01-01', freq='MS')
df = df.pivot('Date','Device','Status').reindex(rng).ffill().fillna('OFF')
print (df)
Device       20   25   50
1989-10-01  OFF  OFF  OFF
1989-11-01  OFF  OFF  OFF
1989-12-01  OFF  OFF  OFF
1990-01-01   ON  OFF   ON
1990-02-01   ON  OFF   ON
1990-03-01   ON   ON   ON
1990-04-01   ON   ON   ON
1990-05-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-06-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-07-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-08-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-09-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-10-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-11-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1990-12-01  OFF   ON  OFF
1991-01-01  OFF   ON  OFF
```

Last if need original format of `dates` add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y/%m')
print (df)
Device    20   25   50
1989/10  OFF  OFF  OFF
1989/11  OFF  OFF  OFF
1989/12  OFF  OFF  OFF
1990/01   ON  OFF   ON
1990/02   ON  OFF   ON
1990/03   ON   ON   ON
1990/04   ON   ON   ON
1990/05  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/06  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/07  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/08  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/09  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/10  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/11  OFF   ON  OFF
1990/12  OFF   ON  OFF
1991/01  OFF   ON  OFF
```

EDIT:

More general solution:

```
def get_status(df, device, check_date):
    check_date = pd.to_datetime(check_date)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

    rng = pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max(), freq='MS')
    df = df.pivot('Date','Device','Status').reindex(rng).ffill().fillna('OFF')
    #print (df)

    if check_date < df.index.min():
        return 'OFF'
    elif check_date > df.index.max():
        return df.loc[df.index[-1], device]
    else:
        return df.loc[check_date, device]

print (get_status(df, 50, '1990/01'))
#ON
print (get_status(df, 50, '1990/02'))
#ON
print (get_status(df, 50, '1990/05'))
#OFF
print (get_status(df, 50, '1990/09'))
#OFF
print (get_status(df, 50, '1900/01'))
#OFF
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about this kind of solution and for my problem probably is good enough, but I wonder if there is any solution in pandas that preserve this initial matrix. In practice, it'll be rather sparse. BTW I'm trying to do some 'poor-man' solution to slowly changing dimension problem with this.

Comment: @QuantChristo - Unfortunately I have no another solution, only some kind of loop which can test all values less as minimal value - output `OFF` and all values higher as maximal with last value.

Comment: @QuantChristo - comment above was implemented to edited answer.

Comment: @jezrel Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Say that your original dataframe is called `status_df` and that you have converted the `Date` column to `datetime.date` type. Then you can define a function and call it with your `status_df` as the first parameter and the desired `device` and `check_date`

```
def get_status(df, device, check_date):
    # Filter only those entries for this device and with date <= check_date
    filtered_df = df[(df['Device']==device) & (df['Date']<=check_date)]
    # Now sort by date
    filtered_df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
    # Now the last entry of the filtered_df contains the active status at check_date
    # If it is empty choose a default values (say OFF)
    if len(filtered_df) < 1:
         return 'OFF'
    return filtered_df.iloc[-1]['Status']
```

**UPDATE**
In case you don't want to create a new dataframe, you can do it with a simple try statement

```
try:
    return df[(df['Device']==device) & (df['Date']<=check_date)].sort_values('Date').iloc[-1]['Status']
except IndexError:
    return 'OFF'
```